# DatepickerDialog. How to reopen it when invalid date set

Tags: java, android, debugging, datepickerdialog

Alright. so I made a datepicker dialog that opens on a TextView Click.  this part works fine.  my problem happens when i have 2 dates.  if the second date is earlier than the first date, then the datepicker should re-open and ask for a new "valid" date.  This is where i come into my problem.  My code as it is now(below) tells me if the date is wrong, but does not re-open the datepicker to allow me to set a new date.   How can I go about doing that?  I tried making a new method and have the same code in it with a different datepickerdialog, but that overlaps 2 datepickers together and the date selected is always from the second one.

```
    public void onClick(final View v) {
    final Calendar date =Calendar.getInstance();
    int dateyear=date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int datemonth=date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dateday=date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dp=new DatePickerDialog(AddClaim.this, new OnDateSetListener() {                  
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
            int month = selectedmonth;
            date.set(selectedyear, month, selectedday);
            Date myDate = date.getTime();

            String returnDate = finalDate.format(myDate);
            if (call){
                sdate_field.setText(returnDate);
                try {
                    sdate = finalDate.parse(returnDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                try {
                    if (finalDate.parse(returnDate).before(sdate)){
                        Toast.makeText(AddClaim.this, "End date cannot be before Start date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //after this a new datepickerdialog should open....


                    }else{
                        edate_field.setText(returnDate);
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    edate = finalDate.parse(returnDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    },dateyear, datemonth, dateday);
    if (call){
        dp.setTitle("Select Start Date");                
    }else{
        dp.setTitle("Select End Date");
    }
        dp.show(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **boolean** field

```
boolean isValid;
```

Update it from the *onDateSet* method. Set it to **true** if the selected date is valid or else set it to **false**.

And check for the state of the boolean field and re-instantiate the picker if necessary.

Most importantly, I suggest you to create a new class for the picker.

Updating...

```
public static class AppDatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    private String sMonth;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //you logic to set the field to true or false
    }
}
```

So to open the picker you can do the following

```
AppDatePickerDialog datePicker = new AppDatePickerDialog();
datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "YOUR_TAG");
```

You can put the above two lines **inside** the *onDateSet* method, if you want to reopen the picker as per the boolean field.

**Edit**

Inside the *onDateSet* method put the following:

```
if (!isValid) {
    AppDatePickerDialog datePicker = new AppDatePickerDialog();
    datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "YOUR_TAG");
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  My question is HOW to reopen the picker. The check to see if it is valid or not already exists.  Either you answered the question and i missed it or you did not answer my question. I am not looking on what logic to use to open the picker. i am looking on HOW to actually open the datepicker after i set an invalid date.

Comment: i did what you said and it worked. thanks.

the other problem of the double datepicker is still there though.

Comment: yeah. it might be an emulator issue because it does not happen on my phone, but when i go through the failed validity, 2 datepickers pop-up instead of 1.  not sure yet. still working on finding the bug

Comment: Why not remove the first line? only use **datePicker.show(getSupportFra.....**

I am not sure but try it